# Store result of Google maps DistanceMatrix to list of origin-destination pairs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, callback, datatables

I have a web page that displays a list of cities in a jQuery datatable.  I need to calculate each city's distance from a single, given location and put the result into the table.  I am able to loop through the rows of the table and make a call to Google's DistanceMatrix, then read the results correctly in the callback function.  However, in the callback, I need to update a column in the jQuery datatable with the calculated distance.  Since the result arrives asynchronously (with only result and status as params), how do I figure out which result in the return array applies to which of my datatable rows?

I suppose I could search my datatable for the city returned in each result element, but the DistanceMatrix call has often transformed ("geocoded"?) my original search parameters into more specific location strings before returning.

Sample code:

```
    var origins = ["Portland, OR"];
    for (var i = 0; i < oTable.fnGetNodes().length; i++) {
        //build a destinations array resembling the one spoofed in the next row
        //assume < 25 entries or else batch processing
    }
    var destinations = ["Seattle, WA", "San Francisco, CA"];

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: origins,
        destinations: destinations,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, (function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.originAddresses.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[j].distance.text;

                    //how do I know which row number to update?  Using j here doesn't match
                    //correctly on the order of rows.  I could search my data table on city but
                    //result (coded) values frequently differ from my table data

                    //var rowNumberToUpdate = ??;

                    oTable.fnUpdate(distance, *rowNumberToUpdate*, column6);
                }
            }
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The response reflects the order of origins and destinations used inside the request.

So you may use the index inside of rows to get the related address inside origins, and the index inside of rows.elements to get the related address inside destinations.

Inside the loop used inside the callback `destinations[j]` will return the used destination from destinations.

Comment: The destinations[j] value doesn't appear to have the correct orig/dest combination in it...hence my question.  However, maybe the problem exists in the oTable.fnGetNodes() call I make to build the initial array...maybe that's not preserving the order...?